# AngularJS ngBind messes the layout of div on small screens

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a really strange issue when trying to inject some text from the database on a html template using AngularJS. Everything looks well until you change to mobile view or when the screen is really small.

This is my html template:

```
<div class="col-12">
<div class="panel panel-white no-radius">
   <div class="panel-heading border-bottom">
      <h4 class="panel-title">Review</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body padding-left-20 padding-right-20">    
       <div ng-repeat="reviewer in reviewers">
         <div class="row">
             <a href="#" class="pull-left"> <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="assets/images/avatar-2.jpg"> </a>
             <strong>{{reviewer.FirstName}} {{reviewer.LastName}}</strong>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="well" style="height: 100px; overflow:auto; word-wrap:break-word;" >
             {{reviewer.Review}}
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-footer" ng-if='rate'>
                Please leave <strong>{{name}}</strong> a review:
     <textarea class="form-control" ng-model='review' maxlength="900" style="resize:vertical;" rows="3"></textarea>
     <button ng-if='rate' class="btn btn-primary btn-xs margin-top-3" ng-click="leaveReview(review)">Leave review</button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The textarea on the footer is how I add the review into the database.
What I discovered was that if I just insert some text into the html file the layout is perfect but when I want to use ngBind the text forces the div to a larger width on small screens. (only on smaller screens, even when resizing)

I suppose the textarea adds to the input some hidden characters that than mess with my div. (maybe newlines or something similar?)

Sorry if the indentation of the html is not right.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you missed **div** tag to close. I guess it's just typo while you are posting this.

Coming to the issue, It's nothing to do with **AngularJS**, as it's a design issue.

While you are using **bootstarp**, You don't need **row** class inside **col-12** class.

I'm guessing that's one, which is creating design issue. Here you are binding the data to the **div**, which is inside another **div** with class **row**, whose over all parent is another **div** with class **col-12**.

You can simply remove **row** class and try it.

Check this link for better idea, where the layout highlighted red and green colors.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red">
  <h3>Column 1</h3>
     <div class='row'>
        <div  style="background-color:green">This is with "row" inside "colomn grid". This is with "row" inside "colomn grid". This is with "row" inside "colomn grid". This is with "row" inside "colomn grid". This is with "row" inside "colomn grid".</div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red">
  <h3>Column 2</h3>
     <div  style="background-color:green">This is without "row" inside "colomn grid". This is without "row" inside "colomn grid". This is without "row" inside "colomn grid". This is without "row" inside "colomn grid". This is without "row" inside "colomn grid". </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
  <h3>Column 3</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qh5n27bx/

Comment: I have deleted the row divs and still no change. The problem is that if I manually type some long text where the {{reviewer.Review}} is I will get a perfectly responsive layout.

Comment: What I have also tried to do was to copy paste some text from a text area and put it instead of {{reviewer.Review}}. This caused the layout to crash. Which makes me thing there is something about how the text area formats the actual text.

Comment: I can understand better If I get to see to the part of code.